# Why does winston.log('doesn't print anything?')

Tags: winston

I don't know if it's just me, but

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.log('This wont print');
winston.info('But this will.');
```

only prints the second line.

[image]

Why doesn't it print the log? I just want to print log, with a level: log

```
winston.log('log', 'This wont print');
```

Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out it *is* impossible because `log` is not a log level, but `info` is.

<sup>Thanks to @elmigranto in #node.js for pointing it out.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
var winston = require('winston');
:
:
:
winston.level = 'your log level';

This will set the log level to 'your log level'. (Tested with winston 0.7.3)
```

better way use :

```
console.log('your log')
```